# ¿Por qué los nacidos en Madrid son "gatos"?

Tags: etimología, españa, animales

La segunda acepción de [**gato<sup>1</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX) del Diccionario de la Lengua es:

> **2.** `m. y f.` `coloq.` Persona nacida en Madrid.

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Creo que técnicamente solo son gatos los nacidos en madrid de _tercera_ generación. Es decir, no eses _gato_ solo por nacer en Madrid. algun padre y abuelo tienen que hacer nacido en Madrid también, aunque no tienen porque ser _gatos_ ellos mismos.

Answer (score 3):

Tiene que ver con una leyenda (referencias en [edicioneslalibreria.es](http://www.edicioneslalibreria.es/por-que-a-los-madrilenos-se-les-llama-gatos/), [tecuentomadrid.wordpress.com](https://tecuentomadrid.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/por-que-los-madrilenos-se-llaman-gatos/) y [20 Minutos](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-a-los-madrilenos-se-les-llama-gatos/), por ejemplo) segun la cual un joven escaló con gran destreza una muralla, dando una victoria decisiva en la reconquista de Madrid.

> En aquel tiempo, Toledo era la ciudad más importante de la Península. Pero sólo a 60 kilómetros existía Mayrit, una fortaleza militar musulmana de vital importancia estratégica y táctica.
>
> [...]
>
> En ese momento, los guardianes le presentaron a un muchacho al que llamaban “gato” por su agilidad y destreza para escalar muros que otros no podían. Al día siguiente, el joven escaló un alto muro con una soga.
>
> [...]
>
> La leyenda cuenta que gracias al intrépido y ágil Gato se pudo ganar la batalla y se conquistó Madrid. Gato se convertiría en un héroe nacional tan famoso que con el paso del tiempo el término “gato” identificó, primero, a cualquier persona valiente de Madrid, y finalmente su significado se extendió para abarcar a cualquiera que hubiera nacido en la ciudad.

Algunas de esas leyendas dicen que el joven cambió "oficialmente" su apellido a "Gato", después de la hazaña.

El artículo de *TecuentoMadrid* añade además:

> [...]Otra leyenda nos cuenta que en la época cristiana había puertas que por entrar a la ciudad había que pagar tasas o peajes, por lo que, los más hábiles escalaban el muro como auténticos felinos.gatos blog
>
> También es sabido que los tejados del Barrio de la Austrias, era un buen hogar para estos felinos, se decía que en Madrid las ratas no entraban porque los gatos las exterminaban.