# ¿Por qué los nacidos en Madrid son “ballenatos”?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa, animales

Sabía que a los nacidos en Madrid se les denomina **gatos** [**como se plantea  aquí**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/por-qu%C3%A9-los-nacidos-en-madrid-son-gatos), pero he encontrado que la segunda acepción de [**ballenato**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4twFHe6) del DLE es:

> 2. `m. y f. desus.` Natural de Madrid. `Era u. t. c. adj.`

Esta acepción aparece en el DLE por primera vez en 1983, pero ya como *desus.*, mientras que la de "gato" apareece en la edicición de 1899.

¿Se sabe por qué este calificativo? ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre llamar "gato" o "ballenato" a un madrileño? Y ¿hay alguna otra denominación para los naturales de Madrid?

Comment: ¿Está Madrid en un valle, como para decir que son "nacidos en el valle, _valle natos_?

Answer (score 4):

Pues nos vamos a tener que remontar a muy antiguo. He encontrado una entrada en el diccionario español-italiano de Franciosini de 1620 que dice:

> uallenate. [ che è nato in Madrid. di Madrid.

Las primeras ediciones del DLE no recogen esta acepción, pero sí lo hace el diccionario de Terreros y Pando de 1786, que dice:

> BALLENATO. A los hijos de Madrid les dan por chasco el mismo nombre.

Viendo que la forma de escribir la palabra varía según el diccionario, relajo un poco el criterio de búsqueda y encuentro lo siguiente:

> *Siendo, pues, esto así, que uno solo no puede afrentar a reino, provincia, ciudad, república, ni pueblo entero, queda en limpio que no hay para qué salir a la venganza del reto de la tal afrenta, pues no lo es; porque ¡bueno sería que se matasen a cada paso los del pueblo de la Reloja con quien se lo llama, ni los cazoleros, berenjeneros, ballenatos, jaboneros, ni los de otros nombres y apellidos que andan por ahí en boca de los muchachos y de gente de poco más a menos!*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", 1615 (España).

Además de usar el término *ballenato* para referirse a los de Madrid, al parecer *cazolero* era como llamaban a los de Valladolid en tiempos de Felipe III (por su afición a comer cazuelas), según una ficha del *Fichero general*. Los berenjeneros eran los de Toledo (por su afición a las berenjenas) y jaboneros los de Getafe, Yepez y Ocaña, por el jabón que fabricaban.

En otra ficha encuentro más referencias:

> *—¿No bailaréis un poquito
>
>   al hoyo, como en Madrid?
>
>   —Sí, en buena fe. —Pues salid [...]
>
>   —¡Bien lo ha hecho el ballenato!*
>
> 1595-98 Lope Vega - Galán escarm.

No es la única obra de Lope de Vega en la que aparece el término. Al parecer este escritor lo usaba bastante. En una nota a pie de página aclara que el término *ballenato* se usa para los hijos de Madrid o de la Ballena. ¿Hará referencia esto a algún barrio o calle de Madrid? Puede que no, porque en otra ficha leo que para el apodo "tomaron pie de un cuentecillo".

Y por fin en otra ficha encuentro la historia que ha mencionado ukemi en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26246/12637)... pero para apodar a los de Covides de Mena (en el valle de Mena, en Burgos). Se cuenta que "los vecinos de este pueblo, en la antigüedad, eran muy temidos y considerados por muy torpes y poco inteligentes. Ejemplo de ello es, dice, la anécdota del pellejo que es tomado por ballena". ¿Una misma historia que corrió de pueblo en pueblo? En otra ficha se lee:

> Ballen·ato. [apodo de los madrileños ó *hijos de la ballena*, desde que salieron con brío armados de todas armas á detener junto al puente á una ballena que bajaba en una avenida por el Manzanares, y que luego resultó ser una albarda.

Esta nota se encuentra en el libro *La lengua de Cervantes: gramática y diccionario de la lengua castellana en El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha*, de Julio Cejador y Frauca, escrito entre 1905 y 1906.

Sobre otros posibles apodos, no encuentro más que los mencionados *gato* y *ballenato*. Y la diferencia entre ambos apodos a día de hoy yo diría que es práctica: el apodo *gato* se puede entender dado que es más actual, mientras que *ballenato* está completamente en desuso y no te va a entender nadie (salvo los que conozcan la historia).

Comment: Muy interesante. El artículo que enlaza @ukemi (http://www.abc.es/madrid/20141213/abci-ballena-manzanares-madrid-201412112037.html) comienza con: "El mismo el río Manzanares, al que Francisco de Quevedo calificó de «arroyo aprendiz de río», acogió en sus aguas una ballena, según narra la popular leyenda. **Esta anécdota también fue recogida por Cervantes, Lope de Vega y Tirso de Molina.**"

Comment: @Rotten no he encontrado los textos de esos autores en los que mencionan expresamente la anécdota. Lo que sí he encontrado son multitud de textos de los tres haciendo uso de "ballenato". Eso es lo que he recogido en mi respuesta, tratando de investigar más en profundidad de lo que el artículo menciona sin citar fuentes.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. El origen de *«ballenato»*

«El Diccionario Geográfico Popular de Madrid» dice esto sobre su origen, pero [no parece muy fiable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimolog%C3%ADa_popular):

> [Según recoge «El Diccionario Geográfico Popular de Madrid», escrtito por Camilo José Cela Conde](http://www.abc.es/madrid/tops/20140716/abci-gentilicios-raros-madrid-201407111304_1.html), hijo del autor de «La Colmena», en cierta ocasión corrió por la capital la voz de que por el Manzanares bajaba una ballena. Al conocer la noticia, muchos madrileños bajaron a la rivera armados con picas y chuzos con intención de mantar al animal.
>
> Hoy los paseantes no verán ballena alguna, ya que el cetáceo que cuenta el relato anónimo no fue mas que una barrica de vino, que el bodeguero quiso salvar de la corriente a la voz de «va llena». Desde entonces al madrileño también se le denominó **«ballenato»**.
>
> - [***ABC Madrid:** El bodeguero que hizo creer a todo Madrid que una ballena nadaba en el Manzanares*](http://www.abc.es/madrid/20141213/abci-ballena-manzanares-madrid-201412112037.html)

---

#### 2. Otros gentilicios

Aparte de [gato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX%7CJ0X0PpO%7CJ0XH87J), [ballenato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4twFHe6) y [madrileño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NqTfYnY) hay [*matritense*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OdVkfvm) (que viene del nombre latín para Madrid, *Matritum*) y, además, el malsonante [*gilipollas*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=41270).

Manuel Alvar Ezquerra, en su *Diccionario de madrileñismos* incluye más términos:

> [image]
>
> - [***Diccionario de madrileñismos:** Voces patrimoniales y populares de la Comunidad de Madrid*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Diccionario_de_madrile%C3%B1ismos.html?id=pU2RtwAACAAJ)

Hay otros gentilicios más antiguos ya desusados:

> [image]
>
> - [***Gentilicios españoles:** (incluye, apodos y motes, coplillas, dichos, datos...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JALup7c12noC&pg=PA277&dq=%22ballenatos%22+Madrid), Tomás de la Torre Aparicio, José de la Torre (p277, 278)