# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "más chulo que un ocho"?

Tags: expresiones, españa

Leo en Twitter:

> MÁS CHULO QUE UN OCHO. Expresión que tuvo su origen en el tranvía madrileño n°8, que iba de la Puerta del Sol a San Antonio de la Florida. El día de #SanIsidroLabrador iba repleto de castizos, ¡y no hay nada más chulo que un tranvía lleno de chulapos!
>
> <sub>Ensalada de Palabras @EnsaladaPalabra, [Twitter 15 mayo 2020](https://twitter.com/EnsaladaPalabra/status/1261194584488624128)</sub>

Mirando alguna referencia tipo [¿Por qué decimos «más chulo que un ocho»?](http://www.secretosdemadrid.es/por-que-decimos-ser-mas-chulos-que-un-ocho/) parece que va en la misma dirección.

¿Es posible confirmar el origen, así como desde cuándo se utiliza? Claramente no puede ser muy antigua, pues el tranvía se inauguró en Madrid en 1879 (y en 1972 desapareció), según la Wikipedia en [Tranvías de Madrid](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tranv%C3%ADas_de_Madrid).

Comment: Vaya post más [chulo - chulapo](https://dle.rae.es/chulapo?m=form) para celebrar San Isidro.

Comment: @Diego feliz día de tu ciudad, chulapo!

Comment: Relacionadas con madrileños: [¿Por qué los nacidos en Madrid son “gatos”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19494/5481) y [¿Por qué los nacidos en Madrid son “ballenatos”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26244/5481)

Comment: @Diego en [Las palabras provenientes del caló, ¿están únicamente presentes en el castellano de España?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16932/1674) mencioné un tuit que muestra jerga madrileña proveniente del caló

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues sí, parece que en este caso el origen está comprobado y confirmado, se refiere al tranvía número 8 de Madrid, que cubría la ruta entre La Bombilla e Hipódromo, y que se tenía como paradigma de la chulería por la cantidad de chulapos y chulapas que podía llegar a llevar.

Pero la cuestión más bien es cuándo comenzó a popularizarse. Eso ocurrió el 30 de enero de 1917. Posiblemente la frase tenga un origen anterior, pero en esa fecha fue cuando se publicó la novela *Más chulo que un ocho*, de [Joaquín Belda](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaqu%C3%ADn_Belda). Debió de tener un gran éxito, porque tres días después aparecía [este anuncio](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001718357&page=3&search=%22m%C3%A1s%20chulo%22%20ocho&lang=es) en el periódico *El imparcial* de Madrid:

[image: Más chulo que un ocho, agotado]

A partir de esta fecha la expresión comienza a aparecer en textos. De hecho el 3 de febrero de 1917 aparece en *El mentidero* un artículo comentando el título del libro y que verifica el origen de la expresión. Expongo [un fragmento](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003980256&page=10&search=%22m%C3%A1s%20chulo%22%20ocho&lang=es):

> —Oye, ninchi. Hazme la "bonté" de traducirme el adjunto epígrafe...
>   [...]
>   —Pues es un anuncio. Dice: "Novela de Joaquín Belda. Más chulo que un ocho."
>   —¿Que un qué?
>   —Que un ocho. Es un guarismo. Un 8.
>   [...]
>   —iMás chulo que un ocho! —se iba repitiendo don Feliz...—. iRediez con el guarismo! ¿Y qué tendrá un ocho para representar por sí el alma popular del distrito de la Latina?
>   [...]
>   —Ya está. iClaro! ¿Cómo no se me habrá ocurrido antes? "Un ocho", ¡natural! El tranvía de la Bombilla. Eso es.

Es raro poder datar con tanta exactitud el origen de una expresión, pero en este caso ha habido suerte.

Comment: Gracias! Interesante cómo ha ido ampliando su radio de acción y ahora en toda España se usa, sería interesante ver si en Hispanoamérica también